# How to read the property values of a class from another form?

Tags: c#

I have the following class and method in one cs file. I have assigned the property values for the class inside the method.

How do  I read the values that are assigned to the properties in the ReturnValue class using another another form.

```
    public class ReturnValues
    {
        public int startdate { get; set; }
        public string imageurl { get; set; }
        public string headline { get; set; }
        public string fulldownloadLink { get; set; }
        public string imagecopyright { get; set; }
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public int PreviousFileDate { get; set; }
    }

string prtemp_path = Path.GetTempPath();

    public void BingWallpaepr()
    {
        ReturnValues returnValues = new ReturnValues();


        string baseurl = "http://bing.com";

        //set the link for XML
        var xml_link = "http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US";
        string xmlStr;
        using (var wc = new WebClient())
        {
            xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(xml_link); //Downloads the xml page

            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr); //loads the xml page to the string

            XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/images/image");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {

                returnValues.imageurl = node["url"].InnerText;
                returnValues.headline = Regex.Replace(node["headline"].InnerText, "[^A-Za-z0-9 _]", ""); 
                returnValues.imagecopyright = node["copyright"].InnerText;
                returnValues.startdate = int.Parse(node["startdate"].InnerText);

                //download the new image
                returnValues.filename = string.Format(@"\bing_{0}.jpg", returnValues.startdate);
               // MessageBox.Show(returnValues.filename.ToString());

                returnValues.fulldownloadLink = baseurl + returnValues.imageurl;
                wc.DownloadFile(new Uri(returnValues.fulldownloadLink), prtemp_path + returnValues.filename);
}
```

In my other form, I am trying to get the property value like below:

```
namespace CrimePortal
{
    public partial class Loginfrm : Form
{

    public Loginfrm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       PlatformCommands.ReturnValues returnValues = new PlatformCommands.ReturnValues();

        MessageBox.Show(returnValues.startdate.ToString());
}
}
```

but it returns null.

Comment: To provide you with a better answer, may I ask how exactly you are creating the second form?

Comment: the second form is just like a regular form which have a button control. In `click event` for the button, I am trying to display one of the property of the `ReturnValues` class which is in a file called `PlatformCommands.cs`.

Comment: Ok, and how is the second form being created? Is it being opened after some event occurs in the first form?

Comment: it is opened upon starting the application. So technically it is the first form.

Comment: Could you include that part of the code in your question so that I can show you how to wire up the two forms? What matters most is the creation of the second form (not the one being created during application start)

Comment: @NahuelPrieto , I added the code to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `BingWallpaper` as a `void`. It shouldn't be. The declaration should look like this:

`public ReturnValues BingWallpaepr()`

And at the end of the method you should `return returnValues;`

Then, from your first form (login), you need to have a reference to the *instance* of the other form, let's say called `platformCommands`. There are many ways to do this and it depends on how you chose to design and structure your UI.

For example, if you want to instantiate the Platform Commands just before displaying the MessageBox, you could do

```
var platformCommands = new PlatformCommands();
PlatformCommands.ReturnValues returnValues = platformCommands.BingWallpaper();
MessageBox.Show(returnValues.startdate.ToString());
```